# How do you add an extra page to a URL?

Tags: web, dns

I have a domain and my website is up and running, however it only has 1 page. I want to add an additional page to the website, but I don't know how.

For example my website is www.website.com
I want to add another page so I will have: www.website.com/page2

I'm guessing it's simple, but I don't know how. Thanks. I use atspace.com as a host if that makes any difference.

Comment: No flame intended, but that is so basic as to be painful.  Looking at http://www.atspace.com/about/f-a-q-help it looks like they expect you to use FTP to add pages.  Do you know how to use FTP?  They should have sent you some kind of instructionsa bout how to connect to your domain.  Maybe look at something like this: http://how-to-build-websites.com/